# How to correctly add signature fields in a PDF/A document with iText

Tags: android, pdf, itext, pdfa

I'm trying to add N signature fields in a PDF/A document with iText API.
These fields have been correctly added using `addAnnotation` of `PDFStamper`, but the document is no longer PDF/A compliant.
In the PDF validation I get the following error:

> The XMP property 'xmp:ModifyDate' is not synchronized with the document information entry 'ModDate'

How can I get a document conforms to the PDF/A standard?

**Update**:  Now I'm using PdfAStamper (itext-pdfa-5.5.1) and itextg (itextg-5.5.1) for Android. But I get the same validation error-

Some code here:

```
String pdfFileName = pdfFile.getAbsolutePath();
PdfReader pdf = new PdfReader(pdfFileName);

tempFile = new File(pdfFileName.substring(0, pdfFileName.lastIndexOf(File.separator)) + "/_pdfSignFieldtemp_" + pdfFile.getName());
tempOutStream = new FileOutputStream(tempFile.getAbsolutePath());
PdfStamper stp = new PdfStamper(pdf, tempOutStream);          
PdfFormField sig = PdfFormField.createSignature(stp.getWriter());

(...cut...)

sig.setWidget(new Rectangle(llx, lly, urx, ury), null);

sig.setAppearance(PdfAnnotation.APPEARANCE_NORMAL,PdfTemplate.createTemplate(stp.getWriter(), 0, 0));
sig.setFlags(PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_PRINT);
sig.setFieldFlags(PdfFormField.FF_REQUIRED);

sig.put(PdfName.DA, new PdfString("/Arial 0 Tf 0 g"));

sig.setFieldName(signatureName);

stp.addAnnotation(sig, intpage);
stp.close();
pdf.close();


tempOutStream.close();

pdfFile.delete();
File pdfWithField = new File(pdfFileName.substring(0, pdfFileName.lastIndexOf(File.separator)) + "/_pdfSignFieldtemp_" + pdfFile.getName());
pdfWithField.renameTo(new File(pdfFileName));
```

Comment: For PDF/A specific pdf processing, the iText api meanwhile offers specific variants of its central classes, e.g. `PdfAStamper`. In the recent versions the quality of these variants has improved very much.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Following your suggestions, I'm using PdfAStamper and itextg for Android. But I get the same validation error.

Comment: What are the versions you're using and can you share some code?

Comment: @MichaëlDemey, thanks for the reply. Topic updated.

Answer (score 0):

> The XMP property 'xmp:ModifyDate' is not synchronized with the document information entry 'ModDate'

Both properties should have the same name, meaning xmp:ModifyDate and 'ModifyDate' (instead of ModDate)

P.S. It is an old topic, but still someone might find this answer useful.